# using google-charts javascript statically

Tags: javascript

I've used google charts in my project and noticed that when I'm not connected to the internet, it does not work because it is trying to retrieve something from:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax

In the google_chart.js and jsapi.js.
Is there a way to use google charts statically without internet access?

Comment: Google says you can't. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no.

Per the docs:

> Can I use charts offline?
>   Your users' computers must have access to https://www.google.com/jsapi in order to use the interactive features of Google Charts. This is because the visualization libraries that your page requires are loaded dynamically before you use them. The code for loading the appropriate library is part of the included jsapi script, and is called when you invoke the google.load() method. Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.load or google.visualization code to use offline.

Comment: Great. Now I know I should move away from google charts.